# Installing PHP accelerator on AMPPS

Tags: php, symfony

OK this question may sound lame to some, but after googling for an answer that I could not find I need your help guys.

OK so I am working a OS x Marvicks, Ussing AMPPS as my local server. I installed Symfony project and when i checked config.php to see I my environment is usitable to use Symfony. After fixing few problem i still have this one that I cannot find an answer to.... '`Install and/or enable a PHP accelerator (highly recommended).`'

[image]

Does anyone know how to install PHP APC(accelerator) on AMPPS....?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using ?  If you have 5.5 or 5.6, you can enable the built-in opcache.

Comment: As @Cedric said: As of version 5.5 you can use the built-in opcache. Add this line to your php.ini `zend_extension=/full/path/to/opcache.so` you can read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php)

Comment: I am usinh php version 5.5

Comment: Thx you guys for suggestions: Now i had a look at my extensions for php5.5 and cannot find opcache.os... do i need to install it from somewhere

Comment: I run AMPPS on windows, and inside the AMPPS folder, under `php5.5/ext` I have `php_opcache.dll` which shipped with AMPPS... My guess is it should be there for OS-X also (the equivalent .so file of course, not the dll)

Comment: I also checked `/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.5/lib/extensions/ext` and I can confirm i do not have opcache.os in the list :/